# Could a translation error lead to squares to not be considered as rectangles?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, traduction, choix-de-mot, mathématiques

I'm reading a certain set of kindergarten/lower primary maths textbooks that is written by American authors for a non-American company.

Whenever students are asked to identify the number of rectangles in a given picture, the answer booklet gives the number of oblongs instead of the number of rectangles.

While the topic may be too advanced for kindergarten students, the maths textbooks indeed explicitly say at the bottom of the first page of a textbook at the very first level to tell students that squares are special types of rectangles, where levels 1-4 are for kindergarten students.

Additionally, the accompany guide for teachers devotes a whole page of discussion as to how to teach that squares are special types of rectangles. There's even a paragraph about teaching to kindergarten students. The authors/some of the co-authors of the teacher guides are also authors/co-authors of the textbooks. They have also said that if students are taught that squares are not rectangles, then they will have misconceptions later.

Perhaps, the ones who wrote the answer booklets were not fluent in English while the ones who wrote the textbooks were.

For example

> [picture with 4 circles, 2 triangles, 3 square rectangles, 2 oblong rectangles for a total of 5 rectangles]
>
> Circle ___
>
> Triangle ___
>
> Square ___
>
> Rectangle ___

The answer key would give only the numbers:

> 4
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 2

So, the last line is wrong since it should be 5.

Could this happen in French? Or a French dialect? I mean, is there something specific about the translations of any of the following words 'rectangle, square, oblong, quadrilateral, quadrangle, parallelogram, trapezoid/trapezium, rhombus' that would cause such confusion? I guess the translator/s thought that when English speakers say 'rectangle', it means 'oblong in their language/dialect, but I don't see that as specifically a problem for this particular language.

By the way, are squares considered rectangles in France? Apparently, these things can vary by state, curricula, culture, time, etc. Please provide a document from the education department of your government or something.

P.S. I'm a monolinguist.

Related:

[Are kindergartners supposed to be steered from squares being rectangles?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/13831/)

[In what curricula are “rectangles” defined so as to exclude squares?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/13700/in-what-curricula-are-rectangles-defined-so-as-to-exclude-squares)

[Why do we have circles for ellipses, squares for rectangles but nothing for triangles?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2249741/why-do-we-have-circles-for-ellipses-squares-for-rectangles-but-nothing-for-tria)

[What are/should kids (be) taught about the colour of the sun?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/394471)

Comment: It's not clear from your question where the translation error could have occurred. Are you saying that the answer booklets were translated while the textbooks were not? Who translated what and why?

Comment: @guillaume31 I'm not sure myself. It could be 1. textbooks english originally then read by non-fluent english 2. textbooks non-english originally then translated then read by non-fluent english 3. non-english textbooks read (either by fluent or non-fluent of that language) though that's not the one i came across 4. in any case, it could be that the ones who wrote the answer booklets were not the ones who wrote the textbooks 5. any valid combination of the previous

Comment: Now I'm confused. Is it a hypothetical question? It sounded like you'd had these booklets in your hands before. You must surely know which language they are in?

Comment: @guillaume31 I do know the state the company belongs to, but I don't want to say it out of fear of identification. Thus, I'm posting to various language SE sites. Here, we assume American authors wrote this for a French company. I've seen only English versions. I am not aware that these texts have non-English version. So I don't know where exactly the translation error may have taken place. [In Spanish SE, a user](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/25583/) suggests the people who wrote the answer booklets are not the same as the main (American) authors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the confusion is also possible in French, as is arguably the case with every language that has corresponding terms for *square* and *rectangle* as we understand them in English.

The mistake comes from the fact that when a human sees

> Square ___
>
> Rectangle ___

they will tend to interpret "Rectangle" as "Rectangles that are not squares, since Squares are accounted for just above".

I'm not sure you'll find Western languages that can make this unambiguous.

**Edit**

To clarify: *Rectangle* in French mathematics means "inclusive" rectangle, i.e. squares are a subset of rectangles. That's what you learn in school. See https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carr%C3%A9.

But the **natural tendency** to think that Rectangle presented alongside Square means "non-square rectangles", **remains**. So a French translation of these instructions would remain as ambiguous as the original in English, because on the one hand you've got the formal definition and on the other hand, what your mind will spontaneously interpret.

Comment: But guillaume31, is it possible that there's something specific in the French language that would cause this confusion? Cf: In Mandarin, the term for oblong (exclusive rectangle) is 长方形(的) but the term for rectangle (I guess inclusive rectangle) is 长方形. Thus, for Mandarin, *it's possible* the answer booklets were mistaken due to language issues rather than geometric misconception issues. Cf: For Spanish, it maybe that *it's unlikely*, language would be an issue because Spanish doesn't have a word for inclusive rectangle. Now: What about French?

Comment: It seems you are [right about Spanish](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuadrado). I didn't know that. However, I can confirm that rectangle in French does mean "inclusive" rectangle (see my edit). I know it's the same [in Dutch](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vierkant_(meetkunde)) (vierkant / rechthoek).

Comment: To answer your question - no, translation errors from English to French are not possible in that regard. The ambiguous English instructions you gave as an example will carry over as equally ambiguous in French.

Comment: guillaume31 Thanks! 1. Should the first word of your answer be 'No' instead of 'Yes' in light of recent clarifications? This would mean that any errors are most likely due to geometric misconception rather than the French language 2. I was expecting that French, like Spanish, doesn't have a word for inclusive rectangle, so it wouldn't be an issue in French as in Spanish. Does this mean that French has the same conclusion as Spanish but for a different reason? 3. Does French have a word for exclusive rectangle? 4. Do you disagree with jlliagre?

Comment: guillaume31 wait what does the Spanish Wiki say about whether or not squares are rectangles? My understanding is that in Spain, squares are rectangles (or as they Spanish would say, 'squares are squares or oblongs'), but such translation error likely cannot happen due to the absence of a Spanish equivalent for rectangle.

Comment: **1.** "No" to what? My "yes" was a "yes" to : same confusion possible in English and French. **2. and 3.** French doesn't have a word for exclusive rectangle, unlike Spanish. French and Spanish are different in that regard. **4.** Yes, I disagree with @jiliagre and so does Wikipedia

Comment: Spanish Wikipedia states *En algunas traducciones, **no aceptadas en general**, el cuadrado es un rectángulo de cuatro lados iguales*, and there is no mention of a *cuadrado* being a specialized form of *rectangulo*, which speaks in favor of an "exclusive" definition of rectangle in that language.

Comment: 1. Yes/No: Is there something specific about the translations of any of the following words 'rectangle, square, oblong, quadrilateral, quadrangle, parallelogram, trapezoid/trapezium, rhombus' that would cause such confusion? 2,3,4. Thanks! LOL 5. Oh, I get that first part now since I thought rectangle there was exclusive. But what about later when it says '*Dado que sus cuatro ángulos internos son rectos, es también un caso especial de rectángulo, es un rectángulo equilátero*' ? It also uses the word rectángulo sooo....

Comment: 1. No, the confusion exists in the original text ; translation into French doesn't add or remove any of it. 5. I don't know enough about Spanish ; guess you'll have to ask on http://spanish.stackexchange.com ;)

Answer (score 3):

While technically a square is indeed a rectangle too, French kindergarten students (and more generally people outside mathematicians) are very unlikely to consider it as such.

Here is an excerpt of a [FAQ](http://web.ac-corse.fr/ec-application/file/2775/) for teachers of students from 6 to 9 years old (CP - CE2 / 1<sup>st</sup> grade to 3<sup>rd</sup> grade)

> Par exemple, il n’est pas d’usage de dire qu’une table carrée est rectangulaire, pourtant, du point de vue
>   mathématique, c’est vrai. En mathématiques on peut dire qu’un carré est un rectangle. Ainsi dès le cycle 1 le
>   nombre de côtés des polygones peut être utilisé pour différencier les formes. On peut également travailler,
>   même si cela peut paraître ambitieux, le fait que les rectangles et les carrés appartiennent à une même
>   famille, celle des quadrilatères (figures à 4 côtés) ayant quatre angles droits.

We do not use *rectangle allongé* (oblong rectangle) to describe a geometrical form in French. I'd even expect *carré allongé* (oblong square) to be used in that case.

For example, there is a monument in Nîmes called *[la maison carrée](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maison_Carr%C3%A9e)*, which is not squared but rectangular. Until the 16<sup>th</sup> century, *[carré](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/complement-godefroy/carr%C3%A92)* was used for all rectangular forms so an oblong rectangle was a *carré/quarré long* while the modern square was called *carré/quarré parfait* (perfect square).

A word that encompass oblong rectangles and squares is *quadrilatère* (quadrilateral), but some quadrilaterals like *losanges* (rhombus) are not rectangles.

Including *carrés* in the *rectangle* class might only be teached at the end of primary (CM2 - grade 5) or possibly later, [e.g.](http://passerelle2.ac-nantes.fr/ep-lescourlis-44/2017/06/13/journee-au-college/):

> Nous avons commencé par du calcul mental, ensuite des problèmes de proportionnalités. Puis nous avons travaillé sur la carré, le rectangle et le losange. J’ai appris que le carré était une sorte de rectangle et une sorte de losange. Nous sommes ensuite sortis de la classe.

Here is a also as document stating the fact *carrés* and *rectangles* are exclusives concepts in French.

[Apport pour les apprentissages de l’explicitation des relations d’inclusion de classes, Laurence Dupuch* et Emmanuel Sander, Université Paris 8](http://www.persee.fr/doc/psy_0003-5033_2007_num_107_4_30954)

> Par exemple, par l’analyse de la phrase «Est-ce un carré ou un rectangle ? » , Politzer (1991) montre que l’usage commun du français place les carrés et les rectangles en relation contrastive : ils forment alors deux classes disjointes si bien qu’un locuteur n’a aucune raison de croire qu’une forme rectangulaire puisse être carrée. Ces deux classes n’ont pas lieu d’être réunies et sont également disjointes de la classe des parallélogrammes et des losanges. L’organisation conceptuelle est alors formée de relations exclusives lexicalisées : quadrilatère – parallélogramme – rectangle – losange – carré. De ce fait, la relation inclusive n’est pas lexicalisée, alors que du point de vue de leur définition mathématique, qui est parfois, mais pas systématiquement, énoncée de façon explicite dans les manuels scolaires, les carrés sont des rectangles : «Un carré est un rectangle qui a des côtés égaux » (Math élèm. manuel CM2, 2000, p. 18).

Comment: jlliagre, thanks! So your answer is that you think that **it's possible** (not necessarily probable) that this could be a French language issue? Cf: In Mandarin, the term for oblong (exclusive rectangle) is 长方形(的) but the term for rectangle (I guess inclusive rectangle) is 长方形. Thus, for Mandarin, *it's possible* the answer booklets were mistaken due to language issues rather than geometric misconception issues. Cf: For Spanish, it maybe that *it's unlikely*, language would be an issue because Spanish doesn't have a word for inclusive rectangle. Now: What about French?

Comment: I guess many French people and even more young students do not consider a square to be a rectangle at all. Exceptions would likely be due to a recent lecture stating that mathematical fact.

Comment: jlliagre, I don't understand, according to the translation of the quote, it is not customary that squares are rectangles, pourtant c’est vrai? I'm not asking if **French people** in general are aware of this. I'm asking if there is something if there is something about the **French language** that could serve as basis to say that **it's possible** that the answer booklets were mistaken due to language issues rather than geometric misconception issues. What exactly is your answer please?

Comment: As far as the French **language** is concerned, a *carré* is not a *rectangle*, it even used to be the other way around.

Comment: jilliagre, do you disagree with guillaume31?

Comment: Yes. I do not expect kindergaten and lower primary teachers to use wikipedia as a reference about what a rectangle is. They use everyday's life meaning where a rectangle is not a square. Classifying a square as a rectangle is an advanced topic. I will update my reply with references.

Comment: jilliagre, I noticed your edit without notification. So... 1. *rectangle* - oblong 2. *carré* - square 3. N/A - rectangle ?

Comment: There is no word that encompass oblongs and square in everyday's French. You might say *quadrilatère à quatre angles droits* which defines both *carrés* and *rectangles* and no other geometrical object.

Comment: @jiliagre the last excerpt you added highlights the fact that language definition and mathematical definition are indeed at odds. But maybe we could agree about the answer to BCLC's original question - that a French translation wouldn't change a thing about the comprehension of the exercise by students compared to the English version?

Comment: @guillaume31 I agree with your "already accounted" point but I have not enough knowledge of English to be able to figure out if the cases are really identical or not. The fact is we do not have a single word for the English word "oblong" while the rare French word *oblong* meaning is wider and unhelpful here. What might also make a difference is the age at which students are usually taught squares are rectangles (apparently 6 in the textbook but at least 10 in France).

Comment: @guillaume31 Thanks for commenting on jlliagre's answer! To clarify, this isn't about the comprehension of students. This is about why the answer booklets don't consider squares to be rectangles.

Comment: There are far more chances that booklets don't consider squares to be rectangles because they follow the same intuition that students have than because of language specifics, if you ask me.

Comment: FWIW, I just made a small poll with five kids playing in front of my house, four 10 years old in CM2/last primary grade, and one 8 years old and they were all definitive about the fact squares are **not** rectangles. One told me a rectangle might be made by two squares joined by one side. None of them accepted *rectangle carré* as a correct description of anything.